# Is there a way to adapt machine learning models knowing ex ante that distributions will shift?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, modeling, concept-drift

I am currently working on a topic where I know that the distributions of the output and of the covariates will shift. I know for example that some covariates will at least follow the inflation rate. The goal is to predict the output over time, based on time series. As far as I understand machine learning methods, they suppose constant distributions over time.

I thought about adapting the standardization of the covariates over time but I am not sure it would work.

Is there a method used in this case to adapt the model (regression trees or SVR for example) to take that into account ?

I think this issue can be divided in 2 subparts:

1.
Is there a way to adapt the model knowing approximately by how much the distribution should shift?

2.
 Is there a way if we do not know the potential shift?

Comment: Can your problem be recast as a problem of extrapolating from a nonparametric model?  For example, say you have $y = f(time)$.  If you fit this with OLS, you can extrapolate.  If you fit it with a kernel regression (or a random forest or any other NP algo), you can't extrapolate all that well.  Is your problem fundamentally different from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is [concept drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_drift) which has a lot of research being done in the context mostly of online learning.

To familiarize yourself with the research I would start at [this review paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.58.9085&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (13 years old now) and see related articles.

Generally speaking it's a very hard to learn under concept drift because the iid assumptions break, the challenge is to detect when that happens.

Comment: See also [A Survey on Concept Drift Adaptation][1] and [Learning under Concept Drift: an Overview][2] as overviews.


  [1]: http://www.win.tue.nl/~mpechen/publications/pubs/Gama_ACMCS_AdaptationCD_accepted.pdf
  [2]: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.4784.pdf